# Update/upgrade Azure web role without cscfg

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have an single Azure Web Role CSPKG with multiple CSCFG files for different customers.
When I deploy a new version I need to specify both which package and configuration file to use.
But sometimes there are changes made in the Azure portal that not have been changed in source cscfg files. (Ex: custom logging levels, etc).

Is there any way I can upgrade an existing instance without overwriting existing settings in Azure. (Of course the scheme needs to be the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do:

1. Create a console application which gets the current properties from the Service Management API ([Get Hosted Service Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806) with embed-detail=true, look for the ExtendedProperties element).
2. Have it update your local CSCFG file
3. Deploy the CSPKG and the updated CSCFG file